# Changing a file in a document library with SharePoint web services

Tags: development, document-library, web-services, document

I'm trying to update a file in a document library using the SharePoint web service. The ["CopyIntoItems"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvccopy.copy.copyintoitems%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method from the ["Copy"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvccopy.copy%28v=office.14%29.aspx) web service I use to upload new files returns an error if I try to overwrite a file with it (even after checking out the file). I don't want to use the client object model, because the program should be compatible to SharePoint 2007, but all sample code I found on the net is using this.

Is there a way to accomplish this without deleting and re-uploading the file?

Comment: If you are still having this issue, can you edit your question to include the error message and code?

Comment: @ErinsMatthew Not before Monday, I'm not at work this week. I'll add it then, if I remember.